# Retrieve users (with certain roles) not working on a certain project LINQ ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I''m trying to retrieve users who are (Junior developers OR Team Leaders) and are not working on a certain project with the given id in the action parameter.

i'm using ASP.NET Identity to store the users

this is the view model i'm using in the action.

**AssignedProjectViewModel**

```
public class AssignedProjectViewModel
{
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public Works_on Works_on { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

in the action below. **usersinRole** retrieves a list of ID of users who are Junior Developers & Team Leaders. This works fine.

Then i'm trying to look for users who are of the specified roles(Junior Developers and Team Leader) and  are not working on a certain project with the given id

**SearchTLandJD action**

```
public ActionResult SearchTLandJD(int projectid)
    {

        var usersinRole = context.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId.Equals("d8bff653-2a05-4159-948d-6eabd17de838") || r.RoleId.Equals("3b12d84f-0ecc-4e04-8e9c-ff3d441e2ce0"))).Select(u => u.Id).ToList();

        var searchquery = from p in DBcontext.Projects
                        join work in DBcontext.Works_on on p.Id equals work.ProjectId
                        join member in DBcontext.Users on work.UserId equals member.Id
                        where !(from w in context.Works_on
                                where w.ProjectId == projectid
                                select w.UserId).Contains(member.Id) && usersinRole.Contains(member.Id)
                        select new AssignedProjectViewModel
                        {
                            Project = p,
                            Works_on = work,
                            User = member
                        };


        var users = searchquery.ToList();
        return View(users);
    }
```

how do i achieve that? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, hard-coding the role ids, is a hugely bad idea. Start by first selecting the roles you want to work with:

```
var roleIds = db.Roles.Where(m => m.Name == "Junior developers" || m.Name == "Team Leaders").Select(m => m.Id);
```

Then, you can fetch the users:

```
var users = db.Users.Where(u =>
    u.Roles.Any(r => roleIds.Contains(r.RoleId)) && 
    !u.Works_on.Any(w => w.ProjectId == projectId));
```